# Integrate $\sin(101x)\cdot \sin^{99}x$

Tags: integration

Question is self explanatory; integration of the above (I tried a substitution of $\sin(x)=u$ after getting the integral of $\sin(101x)\cdot \sin^{99}x$.

Comment: Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips on how to type mathematical formulae on this site.  Are you asking for the indefinite integral $\int \sin(101x)\cdot (\sin(x))^{99}dx$?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Hint: $\sin(\alpha\pm \beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta\pm \cos\alpha\sin\beta$.  Try replacing $\sin(100x+x)=\sin(100x)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(100x)$ and then breaking into two integrals and $u$ substituting there.

Comment: Examine $\cos (A-B)-\cos (A+B)$ and see if that helps

Comment: tried that @JMoravitz, on it Mark Bennet

Comment: That won't work now the question is clarified.

Comment: I'm trying by parts after JMoravitz's step

Comment: It's the first integral [here](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/integration-bee-challenging-integrals/), see the comments for a hint and a solution.

Comment: I solved it & only just saw this. I'll be using that for more dope integrals, thanks :).

Comment: @anja.wlotrzewiszczykowycki You're welcome.

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\int\sin\Big((n+1)~x\Big)\sin^{n-1}x~dx~=~\frac{\sin(nx)\sin^nx}n.$

Comment: are there conditions that apply to n? & Thank you for that! :) @Lucian

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, and it is easy to search for them...

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int { \sin\left( 101x \right) { \sin }^{ 99 }x } dx\\ =\int { \sin\left( 100x+x \right) { \sin }^{ 99 }x } dx\\ =\int { \sin\left( 100x \right) (\cos x{ )(\sin }^{ 99 }x) } dx+\int { \cos(100x{ )\sin }^{ 100 }x } dx$$

Now on using Integration By Parts for first integral and leaving the second integral as it is, we get

$$I=\frac { \left( \sin100x \right) \left( { \sin }^{ 100 }x \right)  }{ 100 } -\int { \cos(100x{ )\sin }^{ 100 }x } dx+\int { \cos(100x{ )\sin }^{ 100 }x } dx+c\\ \therefore \quad I=\frac { \left( \sin 100x \right) \left( { \sin }^{ 100 }x \right)  }{ 100 } +\mathcal{C}$$

> I considered $\sin(100x)$ as frist function and $(\cos x{ )(\sin }^{ 99 }x)$ as second function while using integration by parts.